# Prove that (Q, ∘ , *) is unitary commutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, ring-theory

> The question is: Is (Q,∘ ,*) a commutative and unitary ring, where:
>
> a ∘ b = a + b + ab
>   a * b = ab

My observation:
Q has the property of closure under ∘ and has the property of closure under *, since the results of both operations are elements of Q.
Then ∘ is associative since:  *∀ a, b, c ∈ Q: a ∘ ( b ∘ c ) = ( a ∘ b ) ∘ c*
And an element *e ∈ Q* is an identity element since: *∀ x ∈ Q: x ∘ e = x = e ∘ x* where *e=0*
But then -1 does not have an inverse element since:
*∀ a, a' ∈ Q*:
*a ∘ a' =  a' ∘ a = e*
*a + a' + aa' = 0

a' = (-a)/(1+a)*
which means that *a* can't be equal to -1, does that mean that (Q,∘ ,*) is not a commutative and unitary ring?
Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: For insight, note that $a \circ b = (1+a)(1+b)-1$. As you note there can't be an additive inverse in general, and I doubt there's a distributive law either.

Answer (score 1):

$*$ is not distributive with respect to $\circ$ as

$$a*(b \circ c) = ab + ac + abc \neq ab + ac + a^2bc = (a*b) \circ (a*c)$$ in general. For example

$$-1*(-1 \circ -1) = 1 \neq 3 = (-1 * -1) \circ (-1 * -1)$$

However $*$ is commutative as it is the usual multiplication.